# Can someone help me on usb debugging on android 4.1.2

Tags: android, debugging, passwords, adb, protected

when im turning on usb debugging it has a password like this

[im just want to install custom recovery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEo20.jpg)
so because that i cant install custom recovery

enabling developer>enabling usb debugging>password pop up>cancel = usb debugging disabled

Comment: You don't need adb for installing a custom ROM.

Comment: but how to install the custom recovery

Comment: That depends on the phone. Most phones can be flashed via fastboot. Only phone from Samsung and those with MediaTek CPU have own flash software.

Comment: but the phone fastboot not detected even driver already installed

Comment: and kingroot not working again

Comment: When you enable USB debugging this enables adb not fastboot. Adb is not fastboot. Fastboot is when you reboot to bootloader. Then your device is available via fastboot. Most devices boot into fastboot by holding certain keys at boot time.

Comment: usb detected on the recovery but now the usb is unrecognized

Answer (score 0):

Enter your own password (the password which unlocks your phone when it is locked)

Comment: the phone has no password just slide to unlock

Comment: Try to put one and enable usb debugging by using your new password. (You have to restart your android after the new password have set)

Comment: still not work and it say, password incorrect